# Having issues with MySQL Stored Procedure with multiple statements

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am having a very bad time with a MySQL stored procedure, I can't created this procedure in the database (MySQL 5.5.27)

I a wondering why its rejecting my from variable declaration, multiple select and if else (Hopefully is some code error) I am pasting my code in!

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS EditEnterprise

$$

CREATE PROCEDURE  EditEnterprise(    
    IN pEnterpriseId                VARCHAR(32),    
    IN pEnterpriseName              VARCHAR(64)    
) 

/* declare the new variables */    
DECLARE nEnterpriseId               VARCHAR(32);    
DECLARE nEnterpriseName             VARCHAR(64); 

/* declare the old variables */    
DECLARE oEnterpriseId               VARCHAR(32);    
DECLARE oEnterpriseName             VARCHAR(64);

BEGIN 

SET autocommit = 0;    

/* get the old variables */    
SELECT     
    Enterprise_ID = oEnterpriseId,    
    Enterprise_Name = oEnterpriseName    
FROM     
    enterprise    
WHERE    
    Enterprise_ID = pEnterpriseId;    

/* set the variables with the new inputs */  
IF pEnterpriseName = NULL    
    SET nEnterpriseName = oEnterpriseName    
ELSE IF pEnterpriseName = ''    
    SET oEnterpriseName = NULL    
ELSE
    SET nEnterpriseName = pEnterpriseName    


UPDATE enterprise    
SET     
    Enterprise_Name = nEnterpriseName    
WHERE Enterprise_ID = pEnterpriseId;

COMMIT;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Are you sure, the first `BEGIN` is in the right place?

Comment: Hi Hanlet, I got this error:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE nEnterpriseId               VARCHAR(32);
DECLARE nEnterpriseName       ' at line 7

Euge,
I have tried moving the declare below the begin and I am getting errors too, almost the same as above. Is my placement of the begin wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In Mysql (which differs from Oracle), `DECLARE` goes after `BEGIN`

Your code should be:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS EditEnterprise$$

CREATE PROCEDURE  EditEnterprise(
    IN pEnterpriseId                VARCHAR(32),
    IN pEnterpriseName              VARCHAR(64)
) 
BEGIN 
/* declare the new variables */
DECLARE nEnterpriseId               VARCHAR(32);
DECLARE nEnterpriseName             VARCHAR(64);

/* declare the old variables */
DECLARE oEnterpriseId               VARCHAR(32);
DECLARE oEnterpriseName             VARCHAR(64);

SET autocommit = 0;

/* get the old variables */
SELECT 
    Enterprise_ID := oEnterpriseId,
    Enterprise_Name := oEnterpriseName
FROM 
    enterprise
WHERE
    Enterprise_ID = pEnterpriseId;

/* set the variables with the new inputs */


IF pEnterpriseName IS NULL THEN
    SET nEnterpriseName = oEnterpriseName;
ELSEIF pEnterpriseName = '' THEN
    SET oEnterpriseName = NULL;
ELSE
    SET nEnterpriseName = pEnterpriseName;
END IF;

UPDATE enterprise SET 
    Enterprise_Name = nEnterpriseName
WHERE Enterprise_ID = pEnterpriseId;

COMMIT;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I also added the missing `;`, `THEN` and `END IF` keywords.
Also, take note that you might have a typo at this line:

```
SET oEnterpriseName = NULL;
```

You probably meant:

```
SET nEnterpriseName = NULL;
```

---

Now I think you should reconsider your stored procedure. Indeed, all this could be done in a single SQL query. Do you really need a stored procedure for this? Except if you have a restrictive grants policy it might just be superfluous.

Comment: Thanks Sebas, thanks for this great input, I will be posting a short answer which I kinda figure it out myself. Regarding to its functional validity, this is a simple update query and my initial aiam is to create a table with modular CRUD for future use. I think stored procedure is something which helps to modularize my codes. I am new to SP in mySQL and was working on MSSQL previously!

Answer (score 2):

There are some mistakes in the SP and it should be something like this

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS EditEnterprise
$$
CREATE PROCEDURE  EditEnterprise(
    IN pEnterpriseId                VARCHAR(32),
    IN pEnterpriseName              VARCHAR(64)
)

BEGIN

/* declare the new variables */
DECLARE nEnterpriseId               VARCHAR(32);
DECLARE nEnterpriseName             VARCHAR(64);

/* declare the old variables */
DECLARE oEnterpriseId               VARCHAR(32);
DECLARE oEnterpriseName             VARCHAR(64);

SET autocommit = 0;

/* get the old variables */
SELECT 
    @oEnterpriseID := Enterprise_ID,
    @oEnterpriseName := Enterprise_Name
FROM 
    enterprise
WHERE
    Enterprise_ID = pEnterpriseId;

/* set the variables with the new inputs */
IF pEnterpriseName = NULL THEN  
    SET @nEnterpriseName = @oEnterpriseName;
ELSEIF pEnterpriseName = '' THEN   
    SET @oEnterpriseName = NULL;
ELSE
    SET @nEnterpriseName = pEnterpriseName;
END IF;

UPDATE enterprise
SET 
    Enterprise_Name = nEnterpriseName,
    Enterprise_Established_Date = nEnterpriseCreateDate,
    Enterprise_Description = nEnterpriseDetails,
    Enterprise_Type = nEnterpriseType,
    Enterprise_Status = nEnterpriseStatus
WHERE Enterprise_ID = pEnterpriseId;
COMMIT;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Some errors to point out

- Its ELSEIF instead if ELSE IF for multiple conditions
- After declaring a variable "DECLARE myvar VARCHAR(32)", we need to use := to assign values to it if we are not using the SET command.